# How to set expiry date with HSET function of Redis in Nodejs app with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, redis

While implementing caching in Node express app with typescript. I tried to save data using HSET function, however it is required that stored data should expire after a specified time. Below is the example how I implemented HSET function. I am new to redis and don't know how to set expiry date in HSET function in a typescript code. If someone can give a small example how to do it? Thanks in advance.

client.hSet(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result), 'EX', 10);

Answer (score 0):

`HSET` doesn't support an `EX` modifier - see https://redis.io/commands/hset/

You'll want to do this with two separate commands.  If you want to do them in the same round trip to Redis, pipeline them like this:

```
await Promise.all([
  client.hSet(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result));
  client.expire(this.hashKey, 10);
]);
```